# Is it possible to have a custom filter for exposed criteria?

Tags: views

When I've created a view where the filter criteria is:

```
"Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth) (exposed)"
```

It works well, but I'd like to filter the terms. I have some "`main term`" and a lot of "`sub-terms`" for each "`main term`". What I'd like for this view, is to search ***only*** through "`main term`", i.e. propose in the list only "`main term`", not "`sub-terms`".

How can I achieve this?

If that may help: the parents of main "`main term`"s == 0 (in other words, "`main term`"s have no parents)

Comment: Hi, What's the *drupal*-difference between your terms ? Are main parents of sub ?

Comment: Yes, `sub`terms are children of `main` terms (or you may say `main` terms are parents of `sub`terms, and the parents of `main` terms == `0` (in other words, `main` terms have no parents))

Comment: And I presume chosing them manually in the exposed filter interface doesn't suit your need ?

Comment: No, because I want it to be dynamically generated (i.e. if an admin adds one `main` term, I want it to appear as well in the search filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution that works for me. I've been heavily inspired by this solution which is for Drupal 6, so I've adapted it for Drupal 7 and it works for me:

(Nota: I give two hints in the code : (1) how to make a query that asks for all nodes that have no parent (join on `taxonomy_term_hierarchy` where `parent=0`) and (2) how to search form terms using `LIKE` statement):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function bcg_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form['#form_id']=='views_exposed_form') {
        // override the original completion path which was:
        // 'admin/views/ajax/autocomplete/taxonomy/2'
        $form['term_node_tid_depth']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'admin/bcg/ajax/autocomplete/user';
    }
}

function bcg_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['admin/bcg/ajax/autocomplete/user'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'bcg_ajax_autocomplete_user',
        'access callback' => 'user_access',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
}

/**
 * bcg_ajax_autocomplete_user makes specific autocompletion
 */
function bcg_ajax_autocomplete_user($ajax_search = '') {
    $result = array();
    $vocabularies = taxonomy_get_vocabularies();
    foreach ($vocabularies as $obj) {
        if ($obj->name == 'MY_OWN_VOCABULARY') {
            $vid=$obj->vid;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isset($vid)) {
        $results = db_query(
            'SELECT td.name ' .
            'FROM taxonomy_term_data td ' .
            'JOIN taxonomy_term_hierarchy th ' .
            'ON th.tid=td.tid ' .
            'AND th.parent=0 ' .
            'WHERE (' .
                ' td.name LIKE :name ' .
                'OR ' .
                ' td.description LIKE :name ) ' .
            'ORDER BY 1',
            array(
                ':name' => '%'.$string.'%'
            )
        )->fetchAll();
        foreach ($results as $obj) {
            $result[$obj->name] = $obj->name;
        }
    }
    drupal_json_output($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, subterms are children of main terms (or you may say main terms
>   are parents of subterms, and the parents of main terms == 0 (in other
>   words, main terms have no parents))

You just use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and target your exposed filter.

Use a DB query or [taxonomy_get_tree](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7) (using like `parent=0` and `depth=1`) to get just your `main` terms TIDs.

`unset()` all term value TIDs in the view exposed filter FAPI `#options` that are not found in your list of `$tree` items.

Comment: But I would just like to modify the json call. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Hi, I'm getting close to the final result, but it's far from being simple, and my code is based on this: http://drupalfr.org/forum/support/developpement/21016-resoluhook-form-champ-dautocompletion-et-hook-menu (it's french but look at the latest code)

Answer (score 0):

Other than the hook_form_alter solution already described, there is the [Hierarchical select module](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) on drupal.org.  The module has a pretty comprehensive demo page, so have a look at the second "Taxonomy" tab on its demo page to see its functionality.

Now here's the bad news:  Unfortunately, it doesn't integrate with views yet!  The hierarchical select is still only available on the node edit and node create forms for tagging.  The integration with views is still on its to-do list and active and you can follow that ticket [here](http://drupal.org/node/1170192) (I'm following it myself!).

What I've found is this thread of work-arounds until the much needed feature is released: http://drupal.org/node/1758844.  Includes javascript solutions, as well as somebody who has posted a [module for sale for $20](http://codecanyon.net/item/views-hierarchical-taxonomy-filter/3000280?ref=kervi) with that functionality...

Just throwing those workarounds in the mix for you, in case they're helpful!

Comment: Thank you very much I'll try... -Grumbling time- Like almost all modules for Drupal 7 it's beta or alpha... and I'm wondering when Drupal 8 is out, how many modules of the Drupal 7 will still be alpha or beta...

Comment: The good thing is that this module has over 18,500 sites reporting to use it (so the actual number is higher)... modules like that are typically safe to use.  It's the ones that have 100 installs that I'd be more worried about if you're anxious about the future. ;-)

Comment: I wouldn't make a link between number of users and security: IE 6 to 9 are used by billions of people and 10 years after people still find flaws like two months ago => http://news.cnet.com/8301-1009_3-57514457-83/new-internet-explorer-weakness-already-exploited-in-attacks/ Buy you're 100% right: this is the only 'good' way we can think when talking about Drupal modules: the more users the safer it should be. Thank you again for your suggestion.

Comment: Well, Drupal 7 core, itself, currently has 11150 open issues in its queue, but you're using it, right?  I didn't mean that a module that's heavily used wouldn't have issues or bugs.  I just meant that a heavily used module is more likely to have lots of interested parties and so is more likely to provide support for reported issues and to have a Drupal 8 version come out (because of increased demand and more developers being involved).  That's all.  There will, of course, be bugs!  :-).  Glad you got your solution working too, by the way, and for *posting* it!!  +1 on that.